# Task List views in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

I have a task list. Manager assign some tasks to the users. We have some views for task list. Now Manager want to view all the tasks assigned to the users. But users not able to view other tasks and they can able to view only their tasks only. 
How to disable the views for users.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, In SharePoint, you can't manage permission per views as OOTB but there's a workaround to achieve this as the following :

**Regarding User View**

- Create a new page > add a list view .
- Edit List View web part .
- Assign `My tasks` view .

[image]

- Now edit permission for this page to allow only users to view it.

[image]

In this case, the users should open this page to view their tasks.

**Regarding Manager View**

Repeat the same steps for a page with a list view web part with `All Tasks` view